# Does aws-cli support *resource count* for a given resource?

Tags: aws-cli

I am beginner to aws-cli. So far, my first exploratory query for a given resource. I find circuitous (and may be costly) ways of fetching entire data and then counting them. For example, number of instances, number of regions, number of S3 objects etc. It will be helpful if this is supported in cli. Is it supported already?

There is no problem with the current cli but this is more of generic enhancement request to avoid circuitous logic at the client side

Ex:
 I'd like to know how many instances I have in a given region. I know I can start with aws ec2 describe-instances and then do some processing.
Same applies to get count of any given resource

A pattern of command(s) I'd be interested:

aws ec2 count-instances

aws ec2 count-users

aws <> count-<>

wherever count is applicable. In some cases, some other aggregators will also be useful (say, total number of cpus etc)

Comment: Sorry, but what is your actual question? Can you please edit your question and describe what you would like to accomplish and what difficulty you are currently facing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a command to get the resource count. Find the example below

```
aws configservice get-discovered-resource-counts --resource-types "AWS::EC2::Instance" --region us-east-1
```

Follow the documentation link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/get-discovered-resource-counts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is it also possible to get this information for a specific time range or date?
For example i want to plot and therefore need the data for all ec 2 instance from the last year on a daily bases.